# Finding the intersection point at infinity of two curves on the projective plane

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-geometry, projective-geometry

I am currently going through the appendix A on Projective Geometry of Silverman & Tate *Rational Points on Elliptic Curves*. In the section about intersection of curves on the projective plane, the authors give the following example:

Find the intersection points of the following two curves (a parabola and a line):

$$C_1 : x + 1 = 0 \text{ and } C_2: x^2 - y = 0$$

The first intersection point is simple to see, it is $(-1,1)$. We now need to find to point of intersection at infinity. We first homogenize the two equations to obtain (reusing notation):

$$C_1 : X + Z = 0 \text{ and } C_2: X^2 - YZ = 0$$

This is where my understanding fails to follow what the book says. From what I get, we want to look at the points at infinity by setting Z = 0. The book however says the following:

> Then $C_1\cap C_2$ consists of the two points $[−1, 1, 1]$ and $[0, 1, 0]$, as may be seen
> by substituting $X = −Z$ into the equation for $C_2$.

For me, this does not make sense for if we substitute as it is instructed, we get that Y = 0 which cannot happen in homogeneous coordinates. Can someone help me resolve this gap in my understanding and find the $[0,1,0]$ point given by the authors? I have tried to read multiple ressources here and they do seem to agree with my method of finding the points at infinity by setting $Z=0$.

Comment: Can you explain more in detail how you get $Y=0$ ?

Comment: You don't get that $Y=0$: substituting in $X=-Z$, one gets $X-X=0$ and $X^2+XY=X(X+Y)=0$, so either $X=0$ or $X=Y$, which when paired with $X=-Z$ gives the two results mentioned. One should also note that the quoted text is not dealing with finding just the intersection at infinity - it's trying to find all the intersections in one go. Plugging in $Z=0$ to find intersections at infinity is indeed the correct move, and if you do it you get $X=0$ and $X^2=0$, leading to $[0:1:0]$.

Comment: @Raskolnikov take $X = -Z$ and replace instances of $X$ in $X^2 - YZ$ by $-Z$ and we find $Y = -Z$ by solving. I admit that this might be wrong though.

Comment: @KReiser I'm sorry but I'm still not following. I get that I should substitute $-Z$ for $X$ instead of the other way around but the following points eludes me. If $X=0$ then by $X=-Z$ we get $Z=0$ and we just get $Y=1$ by the fact that we need it to be one?

Comment: The only point in $\Bbb P^2$ satisfying $X=0$ and $Y=0$ is $[0:1:0]$ - remember that we can scale points arbitrarily in projective space and that at least one coordinate is nonzero.

Comment: Surely you mean "The only point in $ℙ^2$ satisfying $X=0$ and $Z=0$ is $[0:1:0]$" otherwise this would contradict your statement of "You don't get that $Y=0$" right? If so, I think I understand.

Comment: @KReiser correct me if this is incorrect but here's my understanding so far: this is trying to find all points at the same time, therefore we proceed in such a way as the $Z$ disappear through substitution. Then, once we found the affine points, we look for points at infinity which will appear once we set $Z=0$. Since we have $X=-Z$ we get $X=0$ which means that two of our three coordinates are zero and we can't stop looking at the equations and just conclude that $Y = 1$ since we need at least one nonzero.

Comment: Sorry, yes, $X=0$ and $Z=0$, typo. You don't need to do any splitting in to affine/infinity cases if you're going for the quoted method of finding all the intersection points at once.

Comment: Alright, thank you very much!